# Make english language SSRS report in spanish language

Tags: reporting-services

-currently i have SSRS report in English language 
   -i need this available in Spanish language (i.e need every thing in report      label,content into Spanish language)

Comment: what exactly is the problem or the question, how to do that? how to start? how to program it?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing built in to SSRS that can translate the text for you.

Unfortunately, you'll need to do it all your self.

One thing you may consider is having a **Language** parameter. You would choose your languages with the parameter and reference the parameter when displaying text. Your expression would be something like:

```
=IIF(Parameters!Language.Value = "English", "Sales", "ventas")
```

If you have text in your data, that would be a bigger issue. You could have a translation table with Spanish text and link it as a separate column. Then you would choose the column similarly as above:

```
=IIF(Parameters!Language.Value = "English", Fields!Description.Value, Fields!Description_ESP.Value)
```